# Passing custom build options to closure when building with stealjs

Tags: rhino, google-closure-compiler, javascriptmvc, stealjs

I am using JavascriptMVC to build an app with StealJS build functionality. This is my `build.js`:

```
load("steal/rhino/rhino.js");
steal('steal/build').then('steal/build/scripts','steal/build/styles',function(){
    steal.build('evi2/scripts/build.html',{to: 'mylovelyapp'});
});
```

This is working fine. However I would love to use Google Closures `@define` syntax to change a few variables on build time. While it would be perfectly simple to modify steals `steal/build/scripts/scripts.js`, I would obviously much prefer to pass the `--define` flags somewhere in my build-script or in my project files.

Any ideas on how to achieve this would be highly appreciated.